# Allocating memory to Array of structs in c++ and Initialisation

Tags: c++, arrays, struct

I am fairly new to c++ programming. At least not very comfortable with the concept of pointers.
Here is a struct that I have defined as a part of a large program

```
typedef struct _MTLinfo {
    char* name;
    GLfloat Ns;
    GLfloat Ka[3];
    GLfloat Kd[3];
    GLfloat Ks[3];
    GLfloat Ni;
    GLfloat d;
    GLuint illum;
    GLfloat Km;
    char* mapKd;
    char* mapbump;
} MTLinfo;
```

Now I want to work with an array of such structs. However,I am immediately thrown with a memory corruption error sometimes and other times also the program does not work fine.

My task is to store certain values in an array of structs. The code I have been trying to get to work is

```
    MTLinfo* readmtl(GLMmodel* glmmodel,char* filename) {
        int index=-1;
        MTLinfo *info;
        /*Line Below is how I am allocating memory */ 
        info=(MTLinfo*)malloc((glmmodel->nummaterials)* sizeof *info) ;
        /* I have some other commands like the one below to store some text*/
     /* into the   array . They are not included because of irrelevance. */
        fscanf(file,"%s",&info[++index].name
```

Also, In some places, I am not initialising any value. For example info[4].d may not be defined anywhere. Should i make every single thing NULL/0 first or is not required? If yes, a small piece of code demonstrating so would help. I have tried a lot but have not been successful

Comment: Don't use malloc in C++. In fact you should be using vector to handle this for you.

Comment: Shouldn't be using the wickedly dangerous `char*` strings in C++ either.

Comment: good luck allocating enough space for that fscanf... someone changes the file a little and it'll overflow the buffer...

Comment: `I am fairly new to c++ programming` However your entire code that you posted is all 'C'. If you were truly using C++, `std::vector`, `std::string` would have been used. In addition, `typedef struct` is a holdover from 'C', as well as usage of `malloc`. So are you really learning C++, or are you reading `C` books and material?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie: Why? Writing low-level C++ is a valid choice... Sometimes. In any case, it does not make it C. (This would not be good C, as he casts from a `void*` to another pointer-type for example)

Comment: @tadman I hate them to be honest.

Comment: @tp1 I never thought of that.

Comment: @PaulMckenzie Actually a friend of mine wrote up some code for a big project for some website and used some library which was in C. As a result the current work is kind of a mixture of C and C++ but honestly I had no clue it was that much of C rather than c++ and its a bit shocking for myself to know that

Comment: I'm 100% with @PaulMcKenzie here. Use the C++ Standard Library unless you have a very, very good reason not to. Writing "low-level" C++ does not mean using `char *`. That's low-level C. That's never been fun and never will be.

Comment: It is part of a big project and I have got almost all of it working using similar char* and fscanfs and mallocs so I was wondering if there was some way to fix this without having to do everything using proper stl from the scratch?
Everything works fine except memory allocation for this array in which there seems some flaw, either due to not allocating properly, or not initialiasing something, not sure what

Comment: @AkashRupela - `It is part of a big project and I have got almost all of it working`  The problem with assuming this is that you have no real proof that it is "almost working", unless you are using serious third-party tools that detects memory leaks, invalid pointer usage, double frees, etc.  That's the problem when you use pointers like this -- you may almost be finished, or may have to scrap the whole thing, even if the program is "almost working".  Also, "almost working" programs that (over)use pointers like this may seem to work but can have hidden bugs.

Comment: @AkashRupela As to geting the program to work -- You need to give us your program in total to fix it.  You have a memory corruption bug, and we have no idea where it could have originated from.  Again, another drawback when you resort to this type of coding.  Unless you can reduce the program to something you can post, I don't see how anyone can help, unless they take a guess at what is wrong and hit the lottery.